# Windows FTP login using "user" command in script fails

Tags: windows, ftp

I have a simple `ftp` script file to upload a file to a server.

Script.txt contains:

```
open ftp.host.com
user Fred PASSword
send c:\hotsheet.dat
disconnect
quit
```

The cmd line is

```
Ftp -s:Script.txt
```

It starts processing correctly but the login fails. I think it is using all lowercase for my password.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows `ftp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp) has two login modes. In the default one (the one you are using), it tries to login automatically once the [`open` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-open_1) is issued and reads the credentials from the script. So the script would have to look like:

```
open example.com
username
password
send c:\hotsheet.dat
disconnect
quit
```

So what is happening with your script is that the `user Fred PASSword` is used as a username as a whole (and similarly the `send c:\hotsheet.dat` is used as a password). You can tell that, if you add `-d` (debug) switch:

```
---> USER user Fred PASSword
331 Please, specify the password.
---> PASS send c:\hotsheet.dat
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
```

---

Or you can prevent the automatic login with `-n` switch:

```
ftp -s:Script.txt -n
```

And then explicitly login using the [`user` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-user), just as your script is doing.

Comment: Martin,Thank you the -n parameter worked petfectly.